# json already loaded error

Tags: php

While executing my PHP code in editor (Eclipse), I am getting this error:

```
PHP Warning: Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0.
```

What's the problem here, and how do I fix it?

My code is

```
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../resources/config.php"));

require_once(LIBRARY_PATH . "/templateFunctions.php");

/*
    Now you can handle all your php logic outside of the template
    file which makes for very clean code!
*/

$setInIndexDotPhp = "Hey! I was set in the index.php file.";

// Must pass in variables (as an array) to use in template
$variables = array(
    'setInIndexDotPhp' => $setInIndexDotPhp
);

renderLayoutWithContentFile("home.php", $variables);
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the code in question. It's your PHP.ini (or another PHP configuration file), usually in /etc/php or /etc/php.ini. Somewhere, you've loaded the JSON module twice.

Comment: I have searched for the JSON in both the php.ini files. I have find the two occurrences but both are commented by ";" (semicolon).

Comment: There might be additional setting files somewhere like /etc/php/conf.d/. Worst case, this warning (not an error!) can be safely ignored.

Comment: How to ignore this worning. After ignoring this shall I go ahead with debugging....

Answer (score 0):

I've done some research in php.ini, and read that I should remove the line:

```
extension=json.so
```