# How to over come from "Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0" error

Tags: php

```
Notice: C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\Work space For Practice\project\resources\config.php line 32 - Undefined index:  DOCUMENT_ROOT
Notice: C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\Work space For Practice\project\resources\config.php line 33 - Undefined index:  DOCUMENT_ROOT
Notice: C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\Work space For Practice\project\resources\config.php line 58 - Use of undefined constant E_STRCT - assumed 'E_STRCT'
PHP Warning:  Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

As I come to know that, this is settings issue.

I am new to PHP, like 1 year kid. So I don't know minimum settings in the php.ini file and other configuration settings also.

please could you help me to overcome from this issue.

Comment: You also have a number of errors in your script, not just setting issues.

Comment: For all the projects it is showing this 'Json' waring. And all those projects are working fine in browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [json already loaded error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575863/json-already-loaded-error)

Comment: Voted to close. You asked the exact same question an hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575863/json-already-loaded-error

Answer (score 0):

First of all go to http://localhost and see there is `phpinfo` on left panel and then see your `PHP version` and tell us then we can help u better

- there is not a constant /define `DOCUMENT_ROOT`

either

```
define('DOCUMENT_ROOT', 'your path')

or use

$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

- there is typo , u definately write **E_STRCT** make it correct

> ```
> error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
> ```

- for JSON module warning

> Please take a look in the php.ini and
>   if the json module is loaded there,
>   comment it out. If you dont find it in
>   the php.ini file, take a look in the
>   conf.d folder in the php configuration
>   directory.

Comment: Where can I find this string, "error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);"    (means in which file)

Comment: at `Practice\project\resources\config.php` line 58   learn to debug error..it is already described on your notice

Comment: See this is one more project. here also it is showing this 'Json' error. Notice: C:\Program Files\OrangeHRM\2.6\htdocs\orangehrm-2.6\lib\exception\ExceptionHandler.php line 65 - Undefined index:  WPATH
Notice: C:\Program Files\OrangeHRM\2.6\htdocs\orangehrm-2.6\lib\exception\ExceptionHandler.php line 84 - Undefined index:  WPATH

Comment: @Gnanendra ..cant u read simple english?? it is clearly written than on line 65 there `WPATH` is written whereas that is not defined before...

Comment: Yes @diEcho, I am able to but As I have seeen that line 65.... $message .= "<?xml-stylesheet href='".$_SESSION['WPATH']."/error.xsl' type='text/xsl'?>\n";

Comment: did u try to echo `$_SESSION['WPATH']` does it print something?? and one more things write `session_start()` should be on top if u r using any session regarding

Comment: Ya I have tried echo $_SESSION['WPATH'] and above that session_start(). But it will stop the execution abnormally. Means it will end up in that statement.

Comment: @Gnanendra .paste your complete code on `www.codepad.org` and refere that link here

Answer (score 0):

Most likely extension is loaded from php.ini file and I would recommend remove that and make sure it's loaded from the module directory.

```
php -i | grep json
```

[image]

There are high chances some modules requires to be loaded in a specific order for ex. json.so needs to be loaded before the mongo.so in that case I would modify like this with priority loading.

[image]

```
; Enable json extension module
priority=20
extension = json.so
```